# How could the concept of finite unbounded universe be compatible with the fact that there are 3 dimensions? Is the example of the balloon a bad one?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, universe, spacetime-dimensions

In cosmology, the current understanding is that the universe is finite while being unbounded.
To explain that, one often uses the example of the surface of a balloon: if we are on the surface of the balloon, there is no bound, while the surface is finite.

The problem is that surface of the balloon has only 2 dimensions, while there is at least 3 dimensions of space in the basic description of the world by physics.

How could the concept of finite unbounded universe be compatible with the fact that there are 3 dimensions? Is the example of the balloon a bad one?

Comment: I don't understand what you think the problem is here. We use the balloon analogy precisely because human minds are not made for visualizing finite-but-boundaryless 3d structures, but where do you think the problem is in stepping from 2 to 3 dimensions? The "balloon" is a 2d sphere, what's the problem with a 3d (4d, 5d...) sphere as finite and boundaryless?

Comment: You could actually start with a 1-D boundless universe, which is a 1-d segment that curves into the 2-d plane. And so on, in an endless series of higher dimensional hypervolumes.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : sorry : I was not aware : so do you mean that the balloon is only an analogy, not a description of the physics model ? Why isn't it a way to graphically represent a finit but boundaryless 3D structure ?

Comment: As you have correctly pointed out, the real world is not 2-dimensional, so of course the balloon is only an analogy. Did you think physicists just forgot that the universe is not 2d and you were the first to notice?

Comment: @ACuriousMind : no I didn't think that physics forgot that the world is not 2D : I thought that there was another reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the shape of the balloon is spherical, and has a radius of $R$. Then it's a 2d surface embedded in 3d space satisfying the equation:

$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2
$$

It is finite and bounded. Similarly, if you want a finite and bounded 3d space, one way to do it is:

$$
w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2
$$

Which defines a 3d space embedded in a 4d space. There are no boundaries to this space, and it has a 3d volume of $2\pi^2R^3$, which is finite.